# Update a tables data conditionally using if or case

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables that are identical in structure. `Table1` holds moderated data, `table2` holds the rest.

**Table 1**

```
+------+--------+---------------+--------+-----------+
| "id" | "name" | "description" | "type" | "country" |
+------+--------+---------------+--------+-----------+
| "1"  | "a"    | "x"           | "1"    | "US"      |
| "2"  | "b"    | "x"           | "1"    | "UK"      |
+------+--------+---------------+--------+-----------+
```

**Table 2**

```
+------+-----------+-----------------+--------+-----------+----------+
| "id" |  "name"   |  "description"  | "type" | "country" | "status" |
+------+-----------+-----------------+--------+-----------+----------+
| "1"  | "Title 1" | "Description 1" | "1"    | "US"      | "2"      |
| "2"  | "Title 2" | "Description 2" | "1 "   | "UK"      | "2"      |
+------+-----------+-----------------+--------+-----------+----------+
```

I run the below sql in order to update `table 1` with data from `table 2`, and it works well. The problem is, a moderator can accept an update or reject it. Accepting an update is done by setting the `status` in `table2` to `0`. Rejecting is done by setting it to `1`.

The update from `table1` to `table2` needs to take place only if a moderator is setting `status` to `0`. That status comes from a php script like `updatestatus.php?status=0&id=1&country=US`

Can an sql be done so that if the the incoming `status` where `0` then `update both tables elseif status = 1 then update only table2 set status = 1 where id=1 and country =us`

```
UPDATE table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b
ON a.id = b.id
SET a.name = b.name,
a.description = b.description
WHERE a.id=1;
```

The way it goes is (roughly):

```
$status = 0;//Php

//sql
if ($status = 0) then (run the above update) 
elseif ($status = 1) then (run update for only table2)
```

I'm ok with using if along with data from inside a table, but how can something like this be done?

**Note**
I cannot use a trigger since I already use one `after update` on `table2`

Comment: Can you not add to your AFTER UPDATE trigger on table 2?  That seems the most logical place to put your code.

Comment: Write a stored procedure that has two updates, one that updates one table for all incoming records, and the other that updates table2 for only those records that have the appropriate status.

Comment: @phillyd The trigger is on `table2` only.

Comment: @CharlesBretana Can I use the value of status inside a stored procedure for `if else`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came this far with a stored procedure.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `p`(IN `status` TINYINT, IN `id` INT, IN `Country` CHAR(2))
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    IF status = 1 THEN
        UPDATE table2 set status = 1 where id = id and country = country;
    ELSEIF status = 0 THEN
        UPDATE table1 a
        INNER JOIN table2 b
        ON a.id = b.id and a.country = b.country
        SET a.name = b.name,    a.description = b.description
        WHERE a.id=id;
    END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no means in the SQL language to update two different tables using a single Update statement. Thus, this type of logic should be done in the middle tier (your PHP code).

Comment: I need to update only one. `if status = 0 (update both - sql is in the question) elseif staus = 1 (update only table2)` It's the if part i'm stuck with.

Comment: @jmenezes - `if status = 0 (update both`. Are you not saying that you are updating both table1 and table2 when the status is zero?

Comment: Ok. That updates only `table1` I can use a second `sql` there. But then, can `if` be used to achieve all this with the status coming from php?

Comment: @jmenezes - Are you asking whether you can created forked code in your PHP which decides whether to update both tables (in two statements) or to update a single table?